# Set date and time into an local variable - Android

Tags: java, android

I have created a form where the user can pick the date and time:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Get the date
    if(v == buttonDatePicker){

        mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        etDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + month + "-" + year);
                    }
                },mYear,mMonth,mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();

    }
    //Get the time
    if(v == buttonTimePicker){

        mHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                etTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
            }
        },mHour,mMinute,true);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

This works fine, but how would you then store the date and time into their own variables, so that I can then store those var into my SQLite database?
I thought creating a date and time object and then setting the from there would do the trick, but when I use date, the get methods are now depreciated.

Do I need to convert the date and time to long vars, like so:

Long pHour = (long) mHour;
and the same for minute, then join them together and then set it via setTime?
but then how do I join them together?

Thanks
If anyone has any doc/tut on doing this that would also be good.

Comment: which one are you using, `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: I am using java.util.Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store in TimeInMillis

```
long storeVal = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

then save storeVal into sharedPreferenses or SQl database

Answer (score 0):

As Radesh proposed you can store dates using `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` which includes date and time, but I prefer to store date/time together as string in this format: `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`.

Comment: Thanks, what would you use to store it as a single format? another long var?

Comment: You must declare 2 string variables strDate and strTime and in the 2 OnDateSetListeners just like you construct the EditTexts by joining year, month, day etc, make your date: `strDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + dayOfMonth` and your time: `strTime = hourOfDay + ":" + minute`. Be careful that you need 4 digits for year and 2 digits for every other. Finally store in your database the result of `strDate + " "  + strTime`

Comment: @mTak Why do you prefer to store date/time together versus storing as a long?

Comment: Because is is very easy to manipulate, comparable, can be converted and parsed easily and if I store it in a database I can see its value directly